# Using ArrayList the right way on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist

I want to program a project like notes application. I am using android studio and I started with this code sample but there is two things I dont understand.

```
else if (getInput == null || getInput.trim().equals(""))
```

First one is why getInput == null is always false.And second one

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformDexWithInstantRunSlicesApkForDebug'.> > java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

I get this error I think I know what it means but I am not sure how to put something like { to the beginning of the arraylist. Thanks in advance.

```
package com.example.mobile;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button1;
    ArrayList<String> addArr = new ArrayList<>();
    ListView list1;
    EditText txt1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        list1 = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        button1 = findViewById(R.id.button);
        txt1 = findViewById(R.id.edit);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String getInput = txt1.getText().toString();

            if(addArr.contains(getInput)){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext() , "Item already exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if (getInput == null || getInput.trim().equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No input is given" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{
                addArr.add(getInput);
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, addArr );
                list1.setAdapter(adapter);
                ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit)).setText(" ");
            }
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing getInput variable already. so, it is never being null. so, getInput==null always returns false

Comment: But it could be empty if user won't write anything in EditText isn't it ?

Comment: It could be empty, yes, but not null. Empty, as in "". It would be null if you just said String getInput; rather than String getInput = txt1.getText().toString(); because in that case it would have no value. An empty string "" technically is a value. I also suggest that you test for that first before checking if the array contains getInput.

Comment: Yeah I reliase that as soon as I post my answer. Thanks for answering my first question guys.

Answer (score 0):

Just like suleyman said, you should check for inputs and other condition before checking if the arrayList has the string. In case of checking if there is an input ori not, instead of

```
getInput.trim().equals("")
```

to check if there is a valid input, you should check it like,

```
if(getInput.trim().length() > 0)
```